# How to access the error object when the Promise of a createAsyncThunk dispatch is rejected?

Tags: typescript, promise, compiler-errors, dispatch, redux-toolkit

I want to handle the cases when a promise is fulfilled and when it is rejected separately. I saw that with my code the first function passed to then is always called, even when the promise is rejected.

I have code like this with the issue explained in a comment:

```
dispatch(reduxActionCreatorHere(/* ...)*/).then((d) => {
  if (d.error) { // TS error: `error` missing from `d`, although the promise is rejected and the `error` field is accessible in pure JS (tested in Chromium DevTools)
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

And like this:

```
export const resetPassword = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/resetPassword",
  async (options: { email: string }, thunkAPI) => {
    debugger;
    return await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        requestPasswordCrud(options.email).then(
          () => {
            console.log("password reset");
            resolve();
          },
          () => {
            reject();
          }
        );
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
);
```

## Update 1

The actual error message is:

```
Property 'error' does not exist on type 'PayloadAction<void, string, { arg: { email: string; }; requestId: string; }, never> | PayloadAction<unknown, string, { arg: { email: string; }; requestId: string; aborted: boolean; condition: boolean; }, SerializedError>'.
  Property 'error' does not exist on type 'PayloadAction<void, string, { arg: { email: string; }; requestId: string; }, never>'.  TS2339
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** *You need to use `unwrapResult` to catch async thunk errors created with `createAsyncThunk`.*

As stated on the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results), a dispatched thunk created with `createAsyncThunk` will always return a resolved promise.
If you want to handle failed scenarios you need to `unwrap` the promise. I would however handle this in the consumer.

```
// action
export const resetPassword = createAsyncThunk("auth/resetPassword", requestPasswordCrud);

// consumer
import { unwrapResult } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const dispatch = useDispatch(); // if you are using react-redux

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(resetPassword())
  .then(unwrapResult)
  .then(actualResponse => {})
  .catch(actualError => {})
}, [])
```

Or you can create an unwrapped dispatch helper:

```
import { unwrapResult } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
const unwrapDispatch = dispatch => thunk => dispatch(thunk).then(unwrapResult);

//consume
const unwrappedDispatch = unwrapDispatch(dispatch);
unwrappedDispatch(resetPassword);
```

**EDIT**: now in @reduxjs/toolkit@1.6.0 promises created with `createAsyncThunk` contain an `.unwrap()` method to automatically unwrap results.